# where to download Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: downloads, versions

I want to download Ubuntu 18.04-standard 18.04.1-1_amd64.tar.gz that can be install in proxmox.
I cannot find where to download. Pls help.

Comment: we do not support questions about end of life products

Answer (score 1):

On the Ubuntu download page, under Alternative downloads, [Past Release](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads):